# Convert XML to text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I need to parse through the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE network SYSTEM "network.dtd">
<network locale="C" version="1.7" attribute_processing="explicit">
<subnet name="subnet_0">
     <attr name="priority" value="0"/>
    <attr name="user id" value="0"/>
    <attr name="x position" value="73.36"/>
    <attr name="y position" value="22.61"/>
    <attr name="outline color" value="blue"/>
    <attr name="creation source" value="Object Palette"/>
    <attr name="creation timestamp" value="16:50:54 Dec 01 2016"/>
    <attr name="creation data" value=""/>
    <characteristic name="units" value="Logical Units"/>
    <view-props>
        <attr name="map" value="world"/>
        <attr name="slice.count" value="0"/>
        <attr name="grid division" value="2e+100"/>
        <attr name="grid style" value="disabled"/>
        <attr name="grid color" value="#808080"/>
        <attr name="resolution" value="2e+100"/>
        <attr name="ul x" value="-50"/>
        <attr name="ul y" value="50"/>
        <attr name="lr x" value="50"/>
        <attr name="lr y" value="-50"/>
        <attr name="iso map names.count" value="0"/>
        <attr name="current view" value="Default View"/>
        <attr name="view mode" value="geographic"/>
    </view-props>
</subnet>
<subnet name="subnet_1">
    <attr name="priority" value="0"/>
    <attr name="user id" value="0"/>
    <attr name="x position" value="75.37"/>
    <attr name="y position" value="19.88"/>
    <attr name="outline color" value="blue"/>
    <attr name="creation source" value="Object Palette"/>
    <attr name="creation timestamp" value="16:50:55 Dec 01 2016"/>
    <attr name="creation data" value=""/>
    <characteristic name="units" value="Logical Units"/>
    <view-props>
        <attr name="map" value="world"/>
        <attr name="slice.count" value="0"/>
        <attr name="grid division" value="2e+100"/>
        <attr name="grid style" value="disabled"/>
        <attr name="grid color" value="#808080"/>
        <attr name="resolution" value="2e+100"/>
        <attr name="ul x" value="-50"/>
        <attr name="ul y" value="50"/>
        <attr name="lr x" value="50"/>
        <attr name="lr y" value="-50"/>
        <attr name="iso map names.count" value="0"/>
        <attr name="current view" value="Default View"/>
        <attr name="view mode" value="geographic"/>
    </view-props>
</subnet>
<subnet name="subnet_2">
    <attr name="priority" value="0"/>
    <attr name="user id" value="0"/>
    <attr name="x position" value="77.42"/>
    <attr name="y position" value="16.63"/>
    <attr name="outline color" value="blue"/>
    <attr name="creation source" value="Object Palette"/>
    <attr name="creation timestamp" value="16:50:55 Dec 01 2016"/>
    <attr name="creation data" value=""/>
    <characteristic name="units" value="Logical Units"/>
    <view-props>
        <attr name="map" value="world"/>
        <attr name="slice.count" value="0"/>
        <attr name="grid division" value="2e+100"/>
        <attr name="grid style" value="disabled"/>
        <attr name="grid color" value="#808080"/>
        <attr name="resolution" value="2e+100"/>
        <attr name="ul x" value="-50"/>
        <attr name="ul y" value="50"/>
        <attr name="lr x" value="50"/>
        <attr name="lr y" value="-50"/>
        <attr name="iso map names.count" value="0"/>
        <attr name="current view" value="Default View"/>
        <attr name="view mode" value="geographic"/>
    </view-props>
</subnet>
<attr name="x position" value="0.0"/>
<attr name="y position" value="0.0"/>
<attr name="creation source" value="Object Palette"/>
<attr name="creation timestamp" value="Unknown"/>
<attr name="creation data" value=""/>
<characteristic name="units" value="Degrees"/>
<view-props>
    <attr name="map" value="world"/>
    <attr name="slice.count" value="9"/>
    <attr name="slice.type [0]" value="mif map"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [0]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [0]" value="world"/>
    <attr name="slice.x [0]" value="0.000000"/>
    <attr name="slice.y [0]" value="0.000000"/>
    <attr name="slice.type [1]" value="shapeset"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [1]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [1]" value="DefaultOcean"/>
    <attr name="slice.x [1]" value="0.000000"/>
    <attr name="slice.y [1]" value="0.000000"/>
    <attr name="slice.type [2]" value="shapeset"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [2]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [2]" value="DefaultWorld"/>
    <attr name="slice.x [2]" value="0.000000"/>
    <attr name="slice.y [2]" value="0.000000"/>
    <attr name="slice.type [3]" value="background objects"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [3]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [3]" value=""/>
    <attr name="slice.type [4]" value="border map"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [4]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [4]" value=""/>
    <attr name="slice.type [5]" value="grid"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [5]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [5]" value=""/>
    <attr name="slice.type [6]" value="shapeset"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [6]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [6]" value="DefaultCities"/>
    <attr name="slice.x [6]" value="0.000000"/>
    <attr name="slice.y [6]" value="0.000000"/>
    <attr name="slice.type [7]" value="orbits"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [7]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [7]" value=""/>
    <attr name="slice.type [8]" value="network objects"/>
    <attr name="slice.ui_status [8]" value="visible"/>
    <attr name="slice.name [8]" value=""/>
    <attr name="grid division" value="2e+100"/>
    <attr name="grid style" value="dashed"/>
    <attr name="grid color" value="#808080"/>
    <attr name="resolution" value="21.8902"/>
    <attr name="ul x" value="35.53"/>
    <attr name="ul y" value="35.7749"/>
    <attr name="lr x" value="97.5669"/>
    <attr name="lr y" value="-5.11096"/>
    <attr name="iso map names.count" value="0"/>
    <attr name="current view" value="Default View"/>
    <attr name="view mode" value="geographic"/>
</view-props>
</network>
```

This XML is from a network simulation tool (OPNET).

I need to parse out the following fields:

```
<subnet name="subnet_0">
<attr name="x position" value="75.37"/>
<attr name="y position" value="19.88"/>
```

I need to iterate this for every instance of `<subnet_name=>`

From these fields I only need the following:

- subnet_0 75.37 19.88. These fields needs to be separated by a space.

I then need to add the following fields:

- COMPONENT <--new field
- {} <--new field
- 0 <--new field
- 75.37 <--from the XML
- 19.88 <-- from the XML
- 0 <--new field
- 180 <--new field
- 360 <--new field
- 3000 <--new field
- HOSTNAME=subnet_0 <--from the XML with "HOSTNAME=" added at the beginning.

The final output should be a separate line for every instance of subnet

For this XML sample the output should look like:

```
COMPONENT   {}  0   73.36   22.61   0   180 360 3000    HOSTNAME=subnet_0

COMPONENT   {}  0   75.37   19.88   0   180 360 3000    HOSTNAME=subnet_1

COMPONENT   {}  0   77.42   16.63   0   180 360 3000    HOSTNAME=subnet_2
```

Please help with the XSLT script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good responses to questions here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (this is of course difficult if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work gives the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: I have just started using XSLT script examples and attempting to modify those examples to get the output I needed. I just wanted a little advice. Maybe a better way tackle this problem. Not even sure if XSLT is the best way. Maybe a Python script would be better. I have been going through a XSLT tutorial too. Thanks again.